# How many conditions of death in which we call a person shaheed or martyr?

Tags: hadith, islamic-basis, martyr

I read about this topic but am.confused that in which condition we call died person is shaheed /martyr or not ? I just want to know about which is declear in hadees or islam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least five different kinds of martyrs according to Islam:

> Abu Hurairah narrated that: The Messenger of Allah said: "The martyrs
>   are five: Those who die of the plague, stomach illness, drowning,
>   being crushed, and the martyr in the cause of Allah" [Jami`
>   at-Tirmidhi 1063](https://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/10/99)

One who dies protecting his property is also considered a martyr :

> It was narrated that Abu Hurairah said: “The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ)
>   said: 'If a man's property is wrongfully targeted, and he is killed,
>   he is a martyr.” [Ibn Majah](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/1268990)

A woman can also be considered a martyr if she dies during childbirth. Similarly, dying of drowning, or burning, or of [pleurisy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleurisy) comes under the same.

> It was narrated from ‘Abdullah bin ‘Abdullah bin Jabir bin ‘Atik, from
>   his father, that his grandfather fell sick and the Prophet (ﷺ) came to
>   visit him. One of his family members said: “We hoped that when he died
>   it would be as a martyr in the cause of Allah.” The Messenger of Allah
>   (ﷺ) said: “In that case the martyrs of my nation would be few. Being
>   killed in the cause of Allah is martyrdom; dying of the plague is
>   martyrdom; **when a pregnant woman dies in childbirth that is martyrdom**;
>   and **dying of drowning, or burning, or of pleurisy**, is martyrdom.” [Ibn
>   Majah](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/1276520)

Answer (score 0):

the event goes as when the holy prophet pbuh came amongst a group of muslims and asked the people ***"whom do you count to be a martyr amongst you?"***, they said *'o messenger of Allah pbuh, whoever dies in the way of Allah is a martyr.'* He said ***"in that case the martyrs of my community will be very few! He who is killed in the way of Allah is a martyr, he who dies a natural death in the way of Allah is a martyr, he who dies in the plague is a martyr, he who dies of cholera is a martyr."*** here when the holy prophet pbuh said in the way of Allah the first time, he meant **the one who dies in jihad** (can be any jihad, spiritual, mental, physical, and jihad of pen etc.), the second time when the holy prophet says in the way of Allah in the hadith, he means the person **who dies the death of a momin**. and that does not mean a person who is a muslim just by name, but **a muslim by his heart and soul**, who refrains from all forbidden acts and does everything for the pleasure of Allah, the third point he says is about cholera and plague, that does not mean necessarily these two diseases, it may be **a person who dies from a very dangerous, or incurable disease, may it be internal or external.**

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the source of your claim. And also marked all quotes as such!