# people says a woman who gives birth is purified of her sins. Is it true?

Tags: women

Mostly people says a woman who gives birth is purified of her sins. Is it true?Are the sins of a woman who gives birth forgiven?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE. To learn more about our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking the [help]. As to your post: It would rather be the case if she died when giving birth as she would be considered a martyr (see [How many conditions of death in which we call a person shaheed or martyr](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/50668/how-many-conditions-of-death-in-which-we-call-a-person-shaheed-or-martyr). So far I have no clue for any otherwise saying statement.